# Need a simple system that boots into a browser and nothing else

Tags: server, system-installation, live-usb, chromium, desktop-environments

I'm developing a project and need something rather simple: a computer that boots into a browser. That's it. No other desktop components - no file manager, no icons, no nothing, just a browser that fills the entire display.

One other requirement: the system needs be able to run from a Live USB but also be able to be installed permanently on a computer.

It's pretty clear that I should use Linux as part of the solution. I began to play around with Ubuntu Server and found that creating the browser was pretty easy. I simply installed chromium-browser and then referenced it in ~/.xsession and called startx. Boom, I get my browser and nothing else, exactly what I want.

But there's a problem: Ubuntu Server can only be installed, it won't run Live. But Ubuntu Desktop will. But, it comes with a maze of Display Managers, Session Managers, Window Managers, etc. that take over the display when all I want is just my simple browser and nothing else.

I'm a bit confused by all of that complexity. How do I configure Desktop to do something simple and just boot into a browser and nothing else? Or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: http://justbrowsinglinux.com/ ?

Comment: This community generally refers to a single-use display without full desktop GUI as a *kiosk*, Use that term in your searches, it's been done several times. Your requirement that it include an installer (or maybe that it's a Live system) seems a bit unusual, but is possible: After you have a working system, use [Debian Live](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-live/) to reproduce that system as a Live image.

Comment: @kashish Very interesting project. It looks sort of like what I want although I don't see an option to install. It's also presents a screen with more things than I like. I could try to reverse engineer this, but given that it's an abandoned 6 year old project that leaves out important functionality, it doesn't seem like the right move.

Comment: @user535733 Actually not quite a kiosk. What I didn't say is that I want to produce these bootable USB drives to hand to other people who can run them or install them. I've looked at about 20 different instructions for kiosks over the last 2 days and none of them meets the requirements.

Comment: Can you not do a Full install of Ubuntu Server to USB? Not just a persistent install. For most of Ubuntu a drive is just a drive.